# MAUI Grid column width bug on Android?

Tags: .net, maui

I'm using Grid.ColumnDefinition but the percentage does not seems to work as it should on Android whereas it's working on Windows.

```xml
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Maui.Views.TestMapPage"
             Title="TestMap">
    <Grid >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Color="Blue" />
        <BoxView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Color="Purple" />
        <BoxView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Color="Yellow" />
        <BoxView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Color="Purple" />
        <BoxView Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Color="Red" />
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

And the result is not as expected (20%,60%,20%)

1. Why?
2. Any idea how to fix this?

[image: screenshot]

Edit & answer to questions:

- I'm testing on Pixel 3a XL - API 33 (Android 13.0)
- Changing to MainPage = new Views.TestMapPage(); did not change the grid problem but remove the tabar and the tittle (which is normal)
- It does not work on Pixel 5 - API 33 (Android 13.0)
- To my surprise it works on windows machine
  [image]
- I'm not going to support iOS given the difficulties and requirements needed to even test your app in local...

Comment: this works correctly for me on iOS

Comment: 1) Testing on what device model and OS version? 2) As a test, in `App.xaml.cs`, change `MainPage = new AppShell();` to `MainPage = new Views.TestMapPage();`. (This shows the page directly, instead of inside Shell.) Are the columns correct?

Comment: @Jason I can't test on iOS due to the requirements needed to develop in local, but I tested it on Windows and it's working whereas on Pixel 5 it has the same problem

Comment: @CedricRoyer-Bertrand I've tested your code and it works both on Android and Windows. May I know the version of your Visual Studio, you may need upgrade to the latest one.

Comment: I'm using VS Community 2022 (64-bits) version 17.6.5. According to the installer this is the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have found the issue, it appears that **Grid.ColumnSpan** is the source of the bug. If I try without it

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Maui.Views.TestMapPage"
             Title="TestMap">
    <Grid >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Color="Blue" />
        <BoxView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Color="Purple" />
        <BoxView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Color="Yellow" />
        <BoxView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Color="Purple" />
        <BoxView Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Color="Red" />
    </Grid>  
</ContentPage>
```

I have the following result, and the grid is split as specified.

[image]

There are bugs around this area, even if on different target architecture and slightly different scenario...

- https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/15328
- https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/15018

I guess I'll have no choice to do find a workaround until they fix it...anyway I won't use BoxView in the final UI so it might just be fine after all...

Keep Coding :D

Edit: It works correctly with frame

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Maui.Views.TestMapPage"
             Title="TestMap">
    <Grid >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Frame BorderColor="Gray"
               CornerRadius="10"
               Grid.Row="0"
               Grid.Column="0" 
               Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
               BackgroundColor="Blue">
            <Label Text="Frame wrapped around a Label" />
        </Frame>

        <!--<BoxView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Color="Blue" />-->
        <BoxView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Color="Purple" />
        <BoxView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Color="Yellow" />
        <BoxView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Color="Purple" />
        <BoxView Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Color="Red" />
    </Grid>  
</ContentPage>
```

[image]

Comment: The grid might be split as specified, but on row 0 and 2 (the first and last row) the column width is only `1`.  I do think you did want to appear line 0 **completely** in blue ?

Comment: Yes but in order to this I need to use Grid.ColumnSpan and as demonstrated above it's buggy. I have hope that this is BoxView that is buggy and that the other component I will use will not have this problem.